# Android: menu and back button stop working

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, menuitem, back-button

For my android app I have multiple edittexts on the main screen.  If i have the first edittext in focus the menu/back buttons operate fine, if i have any of the other edittexts in focus than neither of them work at all.  I'm not doing anything special regarding the menu/back buttons relative to that edittext, i'm not sure what the cause is? Has anyone run into a similar issue and/or know of the cause/solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have listeners for key events on either edit texts that may override the back key?

Comment: Are you talking about menu and back button on your phone?

Comment: @jlindenbaum No, i'm not doing anything to override the back key.  @yogsma Yes i am talking about the menu and back keys that exist as part of the bottom 4 physical keys on my phone.

Comment: Menu won't work unless you have any menu setup in your app. Back button should go back to previous screen irrespective of any number of edittext fields. I have an app where I have 4-5 edittext fields, but back button works perfect.

Comment: @yogsma I have a menu setup, and it works great, as long as my first edittext has focus, same with the back key.  The back button won't even close my app if i don't have focus on the first specific edittext.

Comment: @Siloid: Without any code or layouts, it will be very difficult to help you. Most likely, you have a bug in your app, as many, many applications have activities with multiple `EditText` widgets, and they all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was have the same problem and I found solution for I was have `OnKeyListener` that `return true;` when I change it to `return false;` the problem was fixed

```
    my_editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // you can use the next line to ensure back button & menu button will return false
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) return false;

   // any other key you don't want to call other listener for it
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER&& event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
     return true;                           
    }
     return false;
    }

});
```

[`OnKeyListener.onKey(android.view.View, int, android.view.KeyEvent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

Comment: I had the same problem but even with Activity.onKeyDown() returning false there was no handling of the key (in this case the back button).  Having it return super() solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

easy fix for me, I had removed the only keyboard app.

just install a keyboard app and the buttons worked again